# usage of PTR_ALIGN in Linux

Tags: c, kernel, linux-device-driver

i have `PCI` device driver where it has used `PTR_ALIGN` but don't understand its usage. So can some one explain me why `PTR_ALIGN` used or any reference to it which i can follow.

Thanks
rabi

Comment: I guess that some memory must be aligned to some extent (page boundary?) to be able to use it as - say - destination for a DMA operation or something like that. But it's impossible to give anything better than this kind of guesses without way more context. Also, you probably shouldn't be dabbling with kernel mode code if you don't know what aligned memory is.

Answer (score 3):

PTR_ALIGN is used to align the pointer, as unsigned long variable.

In this case, I think it is best to look on the implementation in Kernel - See http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/kernel.h#L51 for example, don't forget to use the correct Kernel version.

Comment: Fixed @AndyShevchenko